# SSRS : Changing Colour for Different Series

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible that we assign colour for different series ?

[image: Sample Chart]

I would like to assign the colour to the series

`1H = Blue`
`1L = Red`
`PV = Black`

Thanks.

Comment: Please only tag the version of SSRS you are using. And please tell us what control you are using. [For example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-series-colors-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-series-colors-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Chart Series > Fill > Expression ,

=IIF(right(Fields!ItemName.Value,2) = "1L", "RED", IIF(right(Fields!ItemName.Value,2) = "1H","BLUE","BLACK"))